# remove dashed border of the link

Tags: html, css

how can I remove light dashed border of the `a` tag on focus mode?
when you click a link, it becomes dashed.
I set `tabindex:-1` , but it did not make sense.

I want to whether I can remove it?

Comment: If you mess with the focus indicator then make sure you replace it with something else. People who don't use a mouse/trackpad/etc to navigate around a page need to see where they are.

Comment: If you must remove the focus outline, please do it in accordance with this article: http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/04/how-to-remove-css-outlines-in-an-accessible-manner/

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove dotted border around link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007507/how-to-remove-dotted-border-around-link)

Comment: It’s really dotted, not dashed; this is relevant when searching for past questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like:

```
a:active {
    outline: none;
}

a:focus {
    -moz-outline-style: none;
}
```