# How to remove dotted border from submit button and from hyperlink in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove dotted border from submit button and hyperlink that apears after i click on submit button or on hyperlink. I have tried everything what described on google and on stackoverflow but not working any of them.

Tried: [how to remove dotted border around the link in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007507/how-to-remove-dotted-border-around-link)

This the hell has to be removed-
[image]

Comment: We all want our sites to look 100% perfect the way we designed them, but it's worth remembering that this focus indicator is an accessibility feature; users with accessibility issues (eg unable to use a mouse) may need this so they can see where they are on the page.

Comment: @Ravikan - Please note you can answer your own question. The question should not contain answers.

Comment: I agree with @Spudley - this is a useful feature for anyone navigating using the keyboard. It tells the user that a control has focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove it from all elements use this in your stylesheet

```
* { outline: none; }
```

Note that it's not user friendly. Some like to use the tab button to go from one link to the other, with the above code, you can't see which link is selected.

Comment: dear its not working..i am going to remove buttons and will set images there.

Comment: It should... do you have an online example?

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it's not user friendly. But note there's a typo in the code in the answer -- there needs to be a semicolon after `none` otherwise it won't work.

Comment: i am making a desktop application php to exe.i dont have online example.Application is running perfect but it has the above problem. I dont want users letting know that it was created by php,it looks as created in vb.net- i got this code and it seems somthing useful-       a:active, a:focus { 
 outline: none; 
 ie-dummy: expression(this.hideFocus=true);
}