# How to remove border around clicked button in html?

Tags: html, css, border

I have recently started building a website and have started to make buttons on it. However, whenever I click the button, I get a blue border like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TGIX.jpg) !

How should I get rid of this border? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove dotted border around link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007507/how-to-remove-dotted-border-around-link)

Answer (score 12):

Add this css to your button:

```
outline: none;
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add :

```
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The way to remove this is to add this to the css of the button:

```
outline: 0;
```

If you don't want that line anywhere add this to your css:

```
* {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `outline: none;`

here's an example

```
#button
{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
  outline: none;
}
```