# Remove border effect from button

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to remove the blue border from the button which appears every time the button is clicked. No matter what I try it doesn't go. Please see image below for details:

[image: blue border around button1]

Any info on why this issue occurs?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove border around clicked button in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435457/how-to-remove-border-around-clicked-button-in-html)

Comment: @blurfus Looks like few pals here understood the question clearly. Why mark me down if you don't understand what I'm asking? It's a simple problem hence why are you making it more complicated than it is?

Comment: @ASO the question does not meet the community guidelines, for one (read the [ask] page). Secondly, the question has been asked already multiple times.  As such, It should be marked as a duplicate. Third, there are many, many reasons why the border would show up - without a [mre], we are left to guessing as to why this is

Comment: Lastly, ***I*** am not making it more complicated - I am simply following the _community_ guidelines that make SO a great resource.  Instead of blaming me, perhaps consider reading the resources and understanding the reason for these guidelines to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `outline: none;` to the button.

Comment: It's perfect. Nice and neat

Comment: You're welcome ✌

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pure CSS:

```
outline: unset;
```

You might need to add it with the *:focus* selector and/or *:active*.

The outline is used by default in a lot of browsers (especially for mobile UX)